# Making a selection of itms that are the resault of (a positive join of two tables over a third)and (a negative join of two tables over a third)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I want to get a selection of all Articles (ART.ARTKEYI) that are assigned to an Element (PRO.PROKEYI), but whose Element is not assigned to any shop (PSZ.PSZPROKEYI).

the DB is structured so:

Table AEZ connects the Articles (ART.ARTKEYI = 1234) and the Elements (PRO.PROKEYI = 9876)

AEZ:

```
AEZPROKEYI   <-->   AEZARTKEYI

   9876________________1234
```

Table PSZ connects the Elements (PRO.PROKEYI) and the Shops (SHO.SHOKEYI)

PSZ:

```
PSZSHOKEYI <--> PSZPROKEYI

9999999999________9876
```

I want a selection of all ART.ARTKEYI (and ART.ARTBEZC if possible)that are present in  AEZ.AEZARTKEYI (having a corresponding AEZPROKEYI) but only if the AEZPROKEYI is not present in PSZ.PSZPROKEYI

I've tried making the following selection (but I am not really sure if it could even work!)

```
<SQL>
SELECT DISTINCT
artkeyi, artbezc, prokeyi
FROM ART, pro, aez




where 

 aez.aezartkeyi = art.artkeyi
 and
 aez.aezprokeyi = pro.prokeyi
and
proetykeyi = 1 /* only Elements of the 'Product' type*/
 and


not exists (select 1 from CMKAT.pro, psz where pro.prokeyi = 
PSZ.pszprokeyi)
    ;
</SQL>
```

I get a selection of all articles (millions). Should be limited to several thousands.

This needs to be plugged into some Filter function in the program we use, where some preconditions apply:
1. Max 2000 chars
2. the 'Select * from ART where' is a given

When I try to run the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
art.artkeyi 

FROM CMKAT.AEZ

       INNER JOIN CMKAT.PRO
               ON aez.aezprokeyi = pro.prokeyi
       INNER JOIN CMKAT.ART 
               ON aez.aezartkeyi = art.artkeyi




and pro.proetykeyi = 1 



        and

        not exists

(select * from CMKAT.PSZ where pro.prokeyi = PSZ.pszprokeyi)

;
```

I get a selection of ALL articles.

The code needs to be formatted for the filter so:

```
artkeyi IN (SELECT art.artkeyi FROM CMKAT.AEZ  INNER JOIN CMKAT.PRO ON aez.aezprokeyi = pro.prokeyi INNER JOIN CMKAT.ART ON aez.aezartkeyi = art.artkeyi and pro.proetykeyi = 1 and not exists (select * from CMKAT.PSZ where pro.prokeyi = PSZ.pszprokeyi))
```

(I'm not 100% sure about the artkeyi IN part)

Table ART:

```
ARTKEYI, ARTKTYKEYI, ARTKAVKEYI, ARTUNJKEYI, ARTATYKEYI, ARTKOPI, ARTBEZC, ARTINFC, ARTANRC, ARTBNRC, ARTVNRS

18592293    1              1         8486        24260605       InkJet-Papier       225912  225912  71
```

Table AEZ

```
"AEZPROKEYI"    "AEZKAVKEYI"    "AEZARTKEYI"    "AEZUNJKEYI"    "AEZNUMS"   "AEZBPRC"   "AEZBPOC"   "AEZIMPC"   "AEZDLAD"
1813235                1        18592293        12207711        0   ""  ""  "StdImp:"   20.06.18 17:31:26,000000000
```

Table PRO

```
"PROKEYI"   "PROKATKEYI"    "PROKAVKEYI"    "PROETYKEYI"    "PROUNJKEYI"    "PROBEZC"
1813235         1               1              1              12207711  "InkJet-Papier"
```

Comment: Note that SELECT DISTINCT returns distinct _rows_.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, its current result and the wanted result. All as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve too.

Comment: @jarlh 1. ARTs repeat often, hence DISTINCT

This one works, but I need it NOT to include the selection from PRO

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead!

Comment: @jarlh - edited. Sorry, I'm new here. Thanks for the input.

Comment: No problem! Now add some some
sample table data, its current result and the wanted result. All as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a selection of all ART.ARTKEYI (and ART.ARTBEZC if possible)that are present in AEZ.AEZARTKEYI (having a corresponding AEZPROKEYI) but only if the AEZPROKEYI is not present in PSZ.PSZPROKEYI

It sounds like you want `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from art a
where exists (select 1
              from aez az
              where az.AEZARTKEYI = a.AEZPROKEYI
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from psz p
                  where p.PSZPROKEYI = a.AEZPROKEYI
                 );
```

Comment: thanks for your input. There was no result, but it did help me:
    select DISTINCT(art.artKEYI) from CMKAT.ART
    join CMKAT.AEZ on art.artKEYI = aez.aezartkeyi
    join pro on pro.prokeyi = aez.aezprokeyi
    left outer join psz on pro.prokeyi = psz.pszprokeyi
    WHERE psz.pszprokeyi is null
    AND pro.proetykeyi = 1
    ;